# New branch from existing project in git?

Tags: git

I have a project that I've been working on with no initial commit. Recently I did `git init`.

Now I realized that this needs to be in a branch of its own, let's call it `feature-i-should-have-init-first-coded-later`.

How can I move this untracked, uncommited work to the branch while leaving the master empty?

**Update:**
`git status` yields this

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
  noob.txt
```

Comment: show the output of `git branch` here

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest empty. :)

Comment: ok. and `git status`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest See the update :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just `git checkout -b new-branch` here, since nothing is committed to master yet.  You can then stage and commit to the new branch.

Comment: This worked ! ;) Git is now happily tracking `noob.txt` ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t want to commit what you’ve been working on yet - you can **stash** the changes. 
Go through the following steps:

```
git stash
git checkout -b feature-i-should-have-init-first-coded-later
git stash apply
```

Now your new branch contains all recent changes
https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing

Comment: There's no need to stash when creating a new branch like this.  `git stash` followed by `git checkout -b any-new-branch` followed by `git stash apply` is a complete no-op, you may as well have simply checked out the new branch without a stash.

Comment: it's not about just creating a new branch - it's about moving some changes to the certain branch

Comment: Can't `stash` without a commit actually

Comment: Yes, and those changes come along for the free ride, without a stash, because they (a) are not staged or checked in, and (b) are not in conflict with any changes from the checkout (by definition, since it's a new branch).  Give it a try and see.

Comment: "Can't stash without a commit actually" - that's not true. Actually, I did that many times

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Oh my bad :) I didn;t know I could stash without a commit :)

Comment: @emackey, I've already tried that many times. Stash works good when you are dealing with multiple branches and you want to switch branches for a bit to work on something else

Comment: Sure, I use stash all the time and love it.  But it's pointless for this person's question.  You can always create a brand-new branch, preserving un-staged un-committed work, without using any stash.

Comment: @emackey, really? so why when I made changes on some branch1, then created a new branch with `git checkout -b new-branch`  and after switching back  to the branch1 `git status` shows me the uncommitted changes ?

Comment: Because you need to stage & commit to `new-branch` before switching back, to reproduce what is being asked here.

Comment: @emackey, I've considered the author's phrase "How can I move this untracked, uncommited work to the branch" as moving(placing) the uncommitted changes to a distinct branch

Comment: you may want to use `git stash -u` so to stash untracked files as well (and being completely literal to Op's request to move untracked and uncommited files)